# Nginx Rewrite Rules

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

Could you please help me to figure out the following redirection using Nginx?

When a user type [http(s)://(www.)domainA.com/view.php](http://http(s)://(www.)domainA.com/view.php) he/she will be able to access this view.php file (which is in web root)

All other requests which are coming to http(s)://(www.)domainA.com should be redirected to https://learn.domainB.com

(Basically no redirection should be happened only for this view.php file)

My current Nginx vhost file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domainA.com www.domainA.com;

    root /var/www/public_html;

    if ($request_uri !~* (/view.php) ) {
       rewrite ^ https://learn.domainB.com permanent;
    }
    location /view\.php {
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index view.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer this configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domainA.com www.domainA.com;

    root /var/www/public_html;

    location = /view.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index view.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
       return 301 https://learn.domainB.com;
    }
}
```

There is no need for `if` statement, since nginx processes location orders in from start to end, and uses the first matching location block.

This doesn't help with the problem of `view.php` getting downloaded, there is something on the file that prevents it from getting executed just like Anubioz mentioned.

I also removed the escaping of dot in the `location = /view.php` part, since this is not a regular expression match, and therefore the escape is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You configuration should work just fine, though I'd replace rewrite with 301 redirect:

```
if ($request_uri !~* (^/view.php$) ) {
    return 301 https://learn.domainB.com;
}
```

If you need to pass any parameters to `view.php` (like `view.php?a=b`) then your configuration should look like this:

```
if ($request_uri !~* (^/view.php(\?.*)?$) ) {
    return 301 https://learn.domainB.com;
}
```

Comment: Hello Anubioz, Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Actually, "All other requests which are coming to http(s)://(www.)domainA.com should be redirected to https://learn.domainB.com" is working fine. When I type http(s)://(www.)domainA.com/view.php it tryes to download the php file instead of executing it. (php files are executing fine with other vhosts hosted in the same server. So I support this is not due to a missing php module)

Comment: And what exactly is different from those "other vhosts" which work fine? I'd say the problem is in view.php file itself. Have you forgotten to enable short_tags in php.ini? Can you confirm that `view.php` moved to another vhost works fine? What about moving some other php file on place of view.php?